# How to have InstallData run before another module?

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, sequence

I would like my module's `Setup\InstallData` be run before another module's `Setup\UpgradeData`. Is that achievable?

In my module's `etc/module.xml` I've added:

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
</sequence>
```

But that doesn't seem to help – `Setup\InstallData` of my module still gets called only after `Magento\Cms\Setup\UpgradeData`.

(EDIT: OK, I realised that this `sequence` would actually act in reverse - ensure loading the Cms module before mine.)

For now, I've added my data installation code into `Setup\InstallScheme` which *does* get run before `Magento\Cms\Setup\UpgradeData`, but that seems more like a work-around, because the code changes data not DB structure. Also, I'm not sure that `Setup\InstallScheme` doesn't get run before just by chance...

Comment: What do you added? It seems missing in your post.

Comment: I don't think it's that relevant. It's a class `Setup/InstallData` which implements a method `install`  that has content, let's say `error_log("My custom module's InstallData was run.")`
This code gets executed _after_ the other module's (`Magento\Cms`) "Setup\UpgradeData\upgrade", which is what I don't want. I need it to be executed _before_ it.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I now understand what you meant. Edited the question (the code was there but was not displayed due to a missing space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't run any InstallData before any UpgradeData.

```
 // Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand
 $installer->updateModulesSequence($keepGenerated);
 $installer->installSchema();
 $installer->installDataFixtures();
```

You could try to set proper sequence in etc/module.xml and move data installation in UpdgradeData while leaving InstallData empty.

Edit:

Oo, I was wrong ;) actually inside of installDataFixtures all data are installed/upgraded on module basics so the sequence is important however to make a Cms module to be loaded after your you must change sequence in that module which is equal to modifying core unfortunately ;/

Relevant code is in Magento\Setup\Model\Installer on [L:833-899]

Sequence that you have set tells magento that your module depends on cms module and it put your module AFTER cms module in etc/config.php so Install/Upgrade for your module will be executed AFTER cms module.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Then I'll keep my workaround – having the code in "InstallScheme" instead.

Comment: That is most straightforward and works however in some way violate common sense of what this class should do what you actually described in your question. I do not say that i have better solution because i am not fully convinced however you could try to write a plugin for the UpgradeData::execute method because it is a public method. In Plugin you can execute your logic before the main logic. This solution might be better because: 1. it do not violate classes responsibility. 2. it EXTEND and use beforeUpgradeData which is by itself obvious. Keeping upgrade data in install schema is not.

Comment: Whould a plugin be run before the module is actually installed though?

Comment: It is called plugin but it is more like a method wrapper which allow to execute something before, around or after a public method. Therefore if the method itself is called at some point so will be the plugin.